# Error running Invoke-Sqlcmd from ruby when passing path argument

Tags: ruby, powershell, rake, sql-server-2014

```
  def executeSql(sqlFile)
      #exec("powershell $env:gitroot");
      puts "executing file: #{sqlFile}"
      command="powershell Invoke-Sqlcmd -InputFile #{sqlFile} -ServerInstance \"localhost\" -Database \"dbName\" -Verbose"
      command.gsub! '/','\\'
      puts "command: #{command}"
      if($firstRun)
          puts 'inside first run'
          importCommand = `powershell Import-Module \"sqlps\" -DisableNameChecking`
          printf importCommand 
          $firstRun=false
      end
      puts 'made it past first run'
      printf `#{command}`
      puts 'command execution complete'
  end
```

Error

> Invoke-Sqlcmd : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Static'.

When I run this same command in powershell outside of ruby it executes normally.  What am I doing wrong?

### UPDATE

I found that replacing `#{sqlFile}` with the hard coded path `C:\\test\\test.sql` corrects the issue.  I tried `sqlFile.gsub! '/', '\\\\'` and this made no apparent difference (still standard `\` windows path).

I also tried

```
  command="powershell Invoke-Sqlcmd -InputFile #{Shellwords.escape(sqlFile)} -ServerInstance \"localhost\" -Database \"dbName\" -Verbose"
```

which created

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -InputFile C:\\Git\\project\\sql\\db\\01\ -\ Static\ Data\\file.name.here.sql -ServerInstance "localhost" -Database "dbName" -Verbose
```

I think this would have worked were it not for the `01\ -\ Static\` part in the file path.

#### UPDATE 2

I found something that works and posted it as an answer.  @tadman suggested to use multiple args to `system`.  I tried this and it did not work for me.  I'm sure I did something wrong:

```
 testLocation=File.join("C:/test 1", "test.sql")
   executeSql(testLocation)

  def executeSql(sqlFile)
      system("powershell", "Invoke-Sqlcmd", "-InputFile", "#{sqlFile}", "-ServerInstance", "localhost", "-Database", "dbName", "-Verbose")
  end
```

Comment: Instead of composing a shell string, which is easy to get very wrong even if you go out of your way to spike in backslashes all over the place, use `system` and break out the arguments separately: `system('powershell', 'Import-Module', 'sqlps', ...)` This avoids the vast majority of parsing and escaping problems.

Comment: Ruby style also strongly recommends naming methods like `execute_sql` without any upper-case letters. Case has significant meaning in Ruby, with `ClassName` and `CONSTANT_NAME` being examples of that.

Comment: @tadman - I think you are on the right track here.  How do I escape the characters in `#{sqlFile}`?   I believe need to escape them as part of the command path.  Maybe [shellescape](http://apidock.com/ruby/Shellwords/shellescape)?

Comment: You shouldn't have to if you break them out as separate arguments. This bypasses shell interpolation and avoids a lot of ugliness, like filenames with spaces, injecting hostile shell commands and so on. The backtick shell running convention is a very lazy way to do things, good for quick scripts, but completely inappropriate for production code.

Comment: @tadman - If you can provide a working example based off a path with spaces then I'm happy to use it.  I tried to do that and it didn't work.

Comment: I gave you a very specific example there. Passing in each component as a separate argument to `system` is how you fix this. It avoids the `shellescape` dance because it's sent in as a literal argument to your program, which in this case is `powershell`.

Comment: Whatever your solution ends up being, you should probably write a PowerShell wrapper function that does all this dirty work for you so that the code you have here is a lot more straightforward and your solution is re-usable in other parts of your code base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to escape whitespace with backticks to get powershell to behave itself.

```
  def executeSql(sqlFile)
      sqlFile.gsub! ' ','` '#escape whitespace in path
      command="powershell Invoke-Sqlcmd -InputFile #{sqlFile} -ServerInstance \"localhost\" -Database \"dbName\" -Verbose"
      puts "command: #{command}"
      if($firstRun)
          system("powershell Import-Module sqlps -DisableNameChecking;exit")
          $firstRun=false
      end
      system("#{command}")
  end
```